# Security is not working after migration to SP2013

Tags: 2007, 2013, security, migration, user

We have migrated site from MOSS to Sharepoint 2013 by using OOTB Export\Import APIs. Everything is working fine apart from user security. I can see that all the users are migrated to the destination site but when I check their permission it tells that no permission is granted to the user.

I tried adding the same user again from the gui and the security for that particular user started working. I am attaching screenshots of both the user(one which was not working and the one that i added again).

same user is shown twice
[image: same user is shown twice]

This is the user which was migrated OOTB

[image: This is the user which was migrated OOTB]

This is the user that I added through GUI

[image: This is the user that I added through GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Sharepoint 2013 uses Claims based authentication, as opposed to 2007.

You would have to first convert your 2007 envirionment to using claims, before migrating to 2013.

[Here is a guide from Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx) about how to convert a 2010 (yes, not 2007) webapplication to claims, and then migrate to 2013.

The problem I guess is how you should do this from 2007. If first migrating to 2010 is an option, then you have the solution!

Otherwise I think you will have to do some reasearch about how to convert your 2007 webapps to using claims. [I found this link](http://quickanddirtyscripting.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/claims-based-authentication-with-sharepoint-2007/), but I have not tried it and not sure if it covers convertion of an already existing web application though.

My tip is to first migrate to 2010